# Procedure expects parameter which was not supplied - logging says differently

Tags: c#, sql-server, dictionary, parameters

The procedure I'm passing parameters to says I am missing @accountNumber, the dictionary key. I have two methods that use the same code. One works, one does not. Both procedures are also declared the same way, so I am at a loss.

**Edit: Turns out I was missing `comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` in the method.**

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateNumbers_StatementDB]
(
 @accountNumber varchar(50),
 @accountType char(4),
 @padding varchar(50),
 @proc_dateStart datetime,
 @proc_dateEnd datetime
 )
```

Method that calls updateNumbers_StatementDB:

```
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("updateNumbers_StatementDB", osql))
                    {
                        strMsg = "Statement DB";
                        _newLog.LogIt(strMsg);
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in dt)
                        {   //problem parameter
                            var param = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountNumber", item.Key);
                            //item.key shows up in logging as 1020, what I set it as. 
                            strMsg = "item key: " + item.Key;
                            _newLog.LogIt(strMsg);

                            var accountTypeParam = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountType", item.Value);
                            strMsg = "item value: " + item.Value;
                            _newLog.LogIt(strMsg);

                            var paddingParam = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@padding", padding);
                            var dateStartParam = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proc_dateStart", startDate);
                            var dateEndParam = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proc_dateEnd", endDate);

                            var reader = comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); //or NonQuery, etc. 
                            strMsg = "Statement query executed at least once";
                            _newLog.LogIt(strMsg);
                        }
                    }
```

Adding the other method that works:

```
 using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("updateNumbers_ArchiveDB", osql))
                    {

                    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in dt)
                    {
                        var param = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountNumber", item.Key);

                        strMsg = "item key: " + item.Key;
                        _newLog.LogIt(strMsg);
                        var accountTypeParam = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountType", item.Value);

                        strMsg = "item value: " + item.Value;
                        _newLog.LogIt(strMsg);

                        var paddingParam = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@padding", padding);
                        var dateStartParam = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proc_dateStart", startDate);
                        var dateEndParam = comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proc_dateEnd", endDate);
                        strMsg = "Getting to the bottom of the foreach loop";
                        _newLog.LogIt(strMsg);
                        var reader = comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); //or NonQuery, etc. 
                        strMsg = "Query executed at least once";
                        _newLog.LogIt(strMsg);
                    }
                }
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateNumbers_ArchiveDB]
(
 @accountNumber varchar(50),
 @accountType char(4),
 @padding varchar(50),
 @proc_dateStart datetime,
 @proc_dateEnd datetime
 )
```

Usually this error occurs when your variable is null. However, in this case my logging shows the variable has a value. Any ideas as to why my procedure doesn't  see the value?

Comment: Hah, as I went to post the code that works I noticed the problem. I was missing  comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; in the second method. Pays to take a break now and then. Added the code anyway.

Comment: I really don't like "KeyValuePair<string, string> item" for parameter passing.  Not everything in the world is a string.  Just sayin'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing `comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` in the first method.